If a Palestinian converts to Judaism, can they get Israeli citizenship?
If a Palestinian convert to Judaism or even better to the religion of prophet Abraham, can they get Israeli citizenship ?
The Quran does instruct Muslims to follow the religion of Ibrāhīm (Abraham) (which muslims consider to be Islamic Monotheism; the creed of Ibrāhīm is the most primordial precursor to Islam and is mentioned in the Quran in various places - 2:130, 3:95, 4:125, 6:161 and 16:123). E.g:

"Say: "Allah speaketh the Truth: follow the religion of Abraham, the sane in faith; he was not of the Pagans."" (translation by A. Yusuf Ali, Quran 3:95)

Some Jewish scholar however interpret such Quranic verses as an exhortation to muslims to adopt Judaism. Since some Jews are open to the idea of muslims converting to Judaism, if every Palestinian muslim were to "return" to the religion of Abraham, they should be automatically be eligible to be a Israeli citizen and thus the current crisis in the holy land can be solved peacefully.

Did you do some preliminary research on the requirements Israel has for granting citizenship?

Firstly, can you clarify what "the religion of prophet Abraham" is? Do you mean Christianity? Secondly, I think you misunderstand the entire essence of the Israel-Palestine conflict. Most Palestinians don't want to be Israeli citizens; they want to be citizens of an independent Palestine.

I think when the Quran refers to "the religion of Abraham", it means Islam. Note that Christianity, Judaism, and Islam are collectively known as "the Abrahamic religions" and all claim to be the true "religion of Abraham".

@F1Krazy - Indeed, I think the reasoning might even be something like "If the Quran says to follow the religion of Abraham, then some version of Islam is the religion of Abraham. Abraham was Jewish, therefore Judaism is the religion of Abraham. If Islam and Judaism are both the religion of Abraham, then Muslims are Jews." Whether that reasoning is correct or incorrect, who knows, but I think it's pretty unlikely that the Israeli government would accept it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The question would work better if framed from the perspective of an individual Palestinian contemplating conversion to Judaism, as opposed to the idea of all of them converting (which is very unlikely under the present circumstances).

@dan04: that that was sfxedit's edit, not the OP who tied this Q with some plan for peace.

Were would that person be living for the purposes of the question?  In Israel proper?  West Bank?  Gaza?  Lebanon or elsewhere?

simple mis-understanding of Quran when you think Quran instructing Muslims to follow the religion of Ibrahim PBUH implies instructing/allowing them to convert to Judaism. Quran itself rejects this interpretation:

Abraham was not a Jew nor yet a Christian; but he was true in Faith,
and bowed his will to Allah's (Which is Islam), and he joined not gods
with Allah [3:67]

And how could he PBUH be a Christian or Jew when he, the grandfather of Jacob (Israel) PBUH was long before Moses PBUH?
Also there are hints in Quran that describes all the prophets PBUTA and the true believers of them as being Muslims before their teachings were corrupted by others (though had different Jurisprudence), like when the Companions of Jesus the Christ PBUH said:

But when Jesus felt [persistence in] disbelief from them, he said,
'Who are my supporters for [the cause of] Allah?' The disciples
said, 'We are supporters for Allah. We have believed in Allah and
testify that we are Muslims [submitting to Him]' [3:52]

and this was before someone (saint Paul) made a good number of believers to believe in the Jesus PBUH being the God in a flesh, converting then Muslims to Christians afterward. Therefore, converting to Judaism now for a Muslims implies quitting Islam.

However, Palestinian people have shown to care about their beliefs more than they care about their lives/wealth, and promoting convert to Judaism will be more critical to them than promoting the News about Israel's decision to destroy the holy mosque of Quds in favor of building Salamon's temple or anything alike. So, even if Israel would admit to accept converted Palestinians as its citizens, that would not look like a PEACEFUL solution to most of the Palestinians, and those Palestinians who will accept are probably not among those who usually fight for freedom/values.
Meanwhile, although Israel seemingly accepts what you ask about, it is good to mention that not all the Jews (Westerners, Africans, Arabs, etc.) are treated alike in Israel, so that convert would be a outer-side struggling to an inner-side one; perhaps read this.

There is an example of a Palestinian who did this. After being rejected by several rabbis, his request was accepted by the Meir Institute, a prominent Religious Zionist shul, and he was permitted to study there and convert, receiving the name David Ben Avraham.
In March 2024, while traveling to shul, Avraham was stopped on the street by an IDF soldier, who asked him for his name. He gave the soldier his Jewish name, and the soldier laughed at him and told him to put his hands up. When he did so, he was shot dead on the spot. The IDF has refused to release the name of the soldier, but it was learned that he does not speak fluent Hebrew and requested for trial proceedings in English.
As the other answers correctly state, his conversion was not accepted by the national Conversion Authority. However, after his death, he was given permission to reside in Israel. He was buried in the Religious Zionist settlement of Har Brakha.

Looks like this highlights some fissure between different factions in Israeli society.

Israel has a unique "return" law that grants every Jew in the
world the conditional right to become Israeli citizens. However,
conversion in the state of Israel is governed by the Conversion
Authority. That authority does not consider applications from
Palestinians who have converted to Judaism:

Palestinian requests for conversion rejected outright, official says
Rabbi heading government’s Conversion Authority says any such applications are thrown out without even being considered
Rabbi Yitzhak Peretz, director of the Israeli government’s Conversion Authority, spoke about his organization’s handling of requests by Palestinians to convert on Tuesday during a discussion on conversions at the State Control Committee of the Knesset, the Israeli parliament, the news site nrg reported.

So the answer to your question is no. Note that it is not sufficient
for the presumptive Palestinian to "become Jewish" they must also
"become Jewish" as defined by the Israeli state for the purpose of
immigration.

Whoever submitted this suggested edit, you can't just blatantly change an author's answer like that. If you disagree with an answer, leave a comment or submit your own answer.

Unless I'm missing something, the linked article doesn't support the claims that this answer makes about it. This answer claims that "That authority does not consider applications from Palestinians who have converted to Judaism"; but the article says that the authority doesn't consider applications from Palestinians in Israel who wish to convert to Judaism.

@ruakh You are correct, the answer is simply mistaken. The rules of who is "Jewish" for right-of-return are different from who is "Jewish" accd to the Chief Rabbinate of Israel. All the link says is 8 years ago there was an unofficial policy (not law) that the Chief Rabbinate didn't bother reviewing conversion applications from, amongst other, Palestinians. Since then, if that policy is even still in place, the Israeli Supreme Court has reaffirmed multiple times other ways of converting viz-a-viz the RoR law, especially in the Diaspora and even within Israel by other unofficial rabbinic bodies

Many of the above comments are chatty. What evidence is there that my answer is wrong? AIUI, there are no means for Palestinians to be recognized as Jews for the question of citizenship in the eyes of the Israeli state other than to have their conversion approved by the Conversion Authority. And the reports indicate that the Authority discriminates against Palestinians.

@GaslightDeceiveSubvert As noted above, the referenced Conversion Authority manages Orthodox religious conversions in Israel under the Chief Rabbinate (though no longer exclusively). Conversions done elsewhere will still be recognized by the Department of the Interior / Immigration Authority as valid for the Right of Return / Citizenship. In short, you can get citizenship from the State without the Chief Rabbinate recognizing you as Jewish.

Yes, if you have Jewish blood and/or if your conversion is approved by a Jewish community recognized by the Israeli Chief Rabbinate. None exists in the occupied Palestinian territories. I.e., the only possible path to citizenship via conversion is through the CA and it is not open to Palestinians due to ethnic discrimination.

Theoretically, yes.  A Palestinian (or any permanent resident of Israel) who goes through the conversion process would be eligible to become a citizen if they weren't already.
That said, for all practical purposes, this isn't feasible or realistic.  First of all, it's very possible for a Muslim, Christian, Druze, or other minority to be a citizen of Israel, so there's no specific need to convert.  Secondly, actually converting in a way which would be recognized by Israeli courts is a long process that involves a year of study and the whole family actually living a Jewish lifestyle to the satisfaction of a rabbinic judge.
Finally, after converting, the newly Jewish citizen would now be conscripted into military service if they were of the right age and gender (unless they were Druze, in which case they were already subject to conscription).  That could mean being required to take action against other other Palestinians or neighboring Arab countries, regardless of their personal feelings on the matter.
So while this is a thing that happens, it's very rare and definitely not something that would be reasonable to expect to happen en masse.  People's cultural identity is an intrinsic part of who they are, and most people would strongly object to having to make major changes to it.

Moreover, Palestinians are routinely getting Israel citizenship on the order of thousands per year, due to family union, East Jerusalem location or whatnot.

@dEmigOd - Got a link for that? I tried looking it up (searching "Israel family union", but what I found instead was Human Rights Watch talking about an Israeli law that does not allow spouses of citizens who happen to be Palestinian either citizenship, or even residency rights. Its a nearly 20yo story though, so perhaps that's overturned now?

All I got is hundreds per year of East Jerusalem resident granted Israeli citizenship https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2022-05-29/ty-article/why-so-few-palestinians-from-jerusalem-have-israeli-citizenship/00000181-0c46-d090-abe1-ed7fefc20000 and the banning of unification since 2003 https://www.timesofisrael.com/knesset-extends-law-banning-palestinian-family-unification-for-another-year/

@Martheen, the ban was temporary, prolonged every half-year and was removed in 2022.

@dEmigOd my link is from 2023 and states that it ended in 2021 but then resumed in 2022.

Conversion for any other reason than sincere desire to become a Jewish servant of G-D, i.e. material gain or any grand political plan, is prohibited according to Orthodox Jewish law (See Maimonides, Kedusha, Isurai Bi'ah Chapter 13). When a non-Jew askes to be converted, the rabbinical court must investigate to exclude any possibility of material intentions, like marriage and money etc.
According to Maimonides, during the times of king Solomon, which was a great era for the Jewish people in terms of politics and wealth, the grand rabbinical court in Jerusalem refrained from converting any people. Suspecting that the proposed converts are doing so in order to become part of a more successful society.
In order to exclude the possibility of having people converted to Judaism for the sake of obtaining Israeli citizenship, and in line with the Orthodox Jewish tradition, the Israeli chief rabbinate can only convert people who have "already" obtained Israeli citizenship or permanent residence. All others, must receive permission from a special committee. A broad spectrum of people will be automatically declined by the committee, "an illegal alien, people living in the region, legal foreign workers with a B1 visa, legal tourists with a visa of less than 1 year" - It's nothing related to "ethnic discrimination". If a rich white American, working in Israel legally, will wish to convert to Judaism at Israel's chief rabbinate. He will also be declined for the same reason. As chances are high that he just wants Israeli citizenship for business matters.

The interpretation of the verse in OP is incomplete.
Quran also says that if a new messenger comes, the teachings of past messengers become null and void. This is supported by several verses in the Quran, emphasizing that Islam is the final and complete religion that supersedes previous scriptures.
One key verse often cited in this context is:
Surah Al-Imran (3:85):

"And whoever desires other than Islam as religion — never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers."

This verse indicates that after the final revelation through Prophet Muhammad, Allah only accepts Islam as the valid path to His pleasure and salvation, nullifying the previous laws and scriptures.
Additionally, another relevant verse is:
Surah Al-Baqarah (2:106):

"We do not abrogate a verse or cause it to be forgotten except that We bring forth [one] better than it or similar to it. Do you not know that Allah is over all things competent?"

This verse discusses the concept of abrogation (Naskh), where earlier rulings or scriptures can be replaced by newer guidance provided in the Quran, which is considered more suitable for the current time and circumstances.
Together, these verses form the basis of the belief that the Quran, as the final revelation, supersedes previous scriptures and that Islam is now the only accepted religion by Allah.

Regarding the Israeli citizenship
Israeli citizenship laws are primarily governed by the Law of Return (1950), which grants Jews the right to immigrate to Israel and obtain citizenship. According to the Law, anyone who is Jewish or has converted to Judaism under recognized religious authorities can apply for citizenship. However, the situation for Palestinians, particularly those living in the West Bank, Gaza, or with ties to the Palestinian territories, is complicated by security concerns, historical conflict, and other political factors.
While in theory, a Palestinian who undergoes a recognized conversion to Judaism may be eligible to apply for citizenship under the Law of Return, the process may be scrutinized more closely due to security and political concerns.

Nice answer. The Q was naively (or deliberately) mixing religious discourse with politics, and so it is not surprising to see an answer focused on the religious aspect too which others have ignored. After all, if we take that convoluted reasoning in the Q further, one could also argue that if all Israeli Jews convert to Islam, and become Palestinian mulsims, the conflict would end too. (By the way, consider replacing "Allah" with "God". Allah is just Arabic for God, and thus its use in other language is linguistically inappropriate).

@sfxedit Some people have preferences on which word to use https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30935/is-to-say-god-the-same-as-to-say-allah

@Martheen As explained to me, the Quran goes to great lengths to not assign any "idolatry" attribute to God. That includes not assigning a name to God. English speakers using Allah to refer to a "muslim God" (even when the word "God" would suffice) do so to draw deliberate attention to the religious identity aspect (and maybe as a slight against Islamic theology that says all religious books are about the same god). Similarly, referring to muslims as "Muhammedans" also betrays an ignorance of their religion in that muslims don't worship Muhammed or attribute any celestial powers to him.

The answer's usage of "His" indicates that the writer is a Muslim, I think they know what they're doing.

@Martheen An English speaker using "Allah" instead of God is doing so to draw deliberate attention to religious identity. That applies to english speaking muslims too and is worrisome as it is a possible indicator of religious fundamentalism. For example in the urdu speaking community in India, Khuda Hafiz ("God be with you / "May God be your protector") is a common farewell greeting. Lately however, many muslim religious organisations (mostly funded by Saudis) have been instructing their followers to use "Allah Hafiz" instead of the more neutral and multi-cultural "Khuda Hafiz".

@sfxedit and that's their choice

As stated, you do not need to convert to Judaism to become an Israeli citizen.
The question then becomes "can someone with status as a Palestinian become an Israeli citizen?". There is no reason why they couldn't, unless maybe they are known members of terrorist groups like Hezbollah or Hamas in which case they would likely not even be allowed to travel to Israel in order to apply for citizenship (for obvious reasons). This would be no different from anyone else who is a known member of an organised crime syndicate not being able to enter a country.
Of course there will likely be extreme social pressure from their Palestinian peers to not try to gain Israeli citizenship, as their entire social structure is built on what basically amounts to denial that Israel even exists. All Palestinian groups have the destruction of Israel at the core of their founding documents after all. Whether everyone living under those groups actually actively wants this still is of course debatable, but peer pressure and propaganda are very powerful tools to instill sentiment in people (any people, any sentiment, in this the PLO/Fatah in Judea and Samaria would not be any less effective than the Russian government with their campaigns in eastern Ukraine, to give just one example.
But that's not a legal hurdle that would prevent the application in itself, even though the safety of the person after successful application is doubtful (fatwas have been ordered against people for less).

All Palestinian groups have the destruction of Israel at the core of their founding documents after all. - The "destruction" of Israel doesn't have to mean the actual destruction of Israeli citizens. The one state solution theoretically means the destruction of the Israeli state but doesn't mean the erasure of the jewish people or their identity (except ofcourse, for the religious fundamentalist Jews who have made Israel part of their religious identity).

@sfxedit That's what I thought too! Until I read the Hamas Charter, their founding document. It directly quotes the passage about the gharqad tree, I think from a Hadith, maybe The Cow (or is it a sura, or the Koran?) And it says in no uncertain terms, Hamas, that is, not the Koran or any Hadith per se, that every Jew must be killed in Israel. Conversion to Islam might be okay, but it isn't clear about that. I understand about religious fundamentalists, be they Islamic or Judaic, and how they are adamant but unrealistic sometimes, but this is Hamas's own governing doc, so it seems credible

@EllieK "While Hamas’ 1988 founding charter called for the takeover of all of mandate Palestine, including present-day Israel, the new document says it will accept the 1967 borders as the basis for a Palestinian state, with Jerusalem as its capital and the return of refugees to their homes." - Hamas accepts Palestinian state with 1967 borders

@EllieK Israel's biggest curse isn't Hamas, it is its own religious fundamentalists. The extremists in the Palestinian Right want most Israeli Jews killed just as the extremist in the Israeli Right (now carrying out the genocide in Gaza) want all Palestinian muslims dead. Hamas started out as a terrorist organisation just as the Likud party (Irgun > Tnuat Haherut > Likud) did too. But unlike the Likud party, Hamas was never allowed by the US or Israel to transition to a more moderate political party even though it made many attempts to do so.

@sfxedit Israeli liberal progressives and leftists are a HUGE part of Israel's curse as well. They are Israel's elite and they cause riots and misery. They can't get along with Palestinians and they can't get along with Jews. They COULD legitimately complain about the religious Jews who won't serve in the IDF (anyone would understand that, to accept protection without helping too) but they don't even do that!  It is so frustrating. For example, the Qataris are more sane than Blinken. I am not disagreeing or agreeing with you because I know the limits of my knowledge. I'm sorry for ranting.
